# OBJLoader: Unexpected line: "<!DOCTYPE html>" in vue cli3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli-3

I use vue-3d-model component for 3D object viewer in cli3 but stuck with this issue

```js
<script>
    // import { ModelThree   } from 'vue-3d-model'
    import { ModelObj } from 'vue-3d-model'

    export default {
        components: {
            // ModelThree,
            ModelObj
        }
    }
</script>
```

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <h2>3D viewer</h2>
        <model-obj src="../assets/models/obj/LeePerrySmith.obj">             </model-obj>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    // import { ModelThree   } from 'vue-3d-model'
    import { ModelObj } from 'vue-3d-model'

    export default {
        components: {
            // ModelThree,
            ModelObj
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The content of LeePerrySmith.obj is invalid.

Please check it or post the content online.